# NodeJS with MongoDB freezes at find() method

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am working on learning NodeJS by building a very simple pastebin. The code works as long as I do not try to persist the data with MongoDB.

The app freezes while trying to open the 'List All' page.

I zeroed in the issue to be in this part of the code,

```
HoldText = function(){
    this.db = new Db('name', new Server('localhost', 27017, {auto_reconnect: true}, {}), {safe: false});
    this.db.open(function(){});
};

HoldText.prototype.getCollection = function(callback) {
    this.db.collection('texts', function(error, text_collection) {
            if (error) callback(error);
            else callback(null, text_collection);
    });
};


HoldText.prototype.findAll = function(callback) {
    console.log("FLAG0");
    this.getCollection(function(error, text_collection) {
            if (error) {
                    callback(error);
                    console.log("FLAG 1");
            }
            else { 
                    console.log("FLAG 2");
                    text_collection.find().toArray(function(error, results) {
                            if( error ) { 
                                    console.log("FLAG3");
                                    callback(error);
                            } else {
                                    console.log("FLAG4");
                                    callback(null, results);
                            }
                            console.log("FLAG5");
                    });
            }
    });
};
console.log("FLAG6");
```

FLAGS 0,2, and 6 get called. 
Does anyone have any words of advice for me?

Comment: What method getCollection does?

Comment: Have you heard of/considered using [MongooseJS](http://mongoosejs.com/)? It will make your life a lot easier. I built an app without it and then another with it and let me tell you, by using a library you're just making your life easier. MongooseJS makes stuff like this a lot easier IMO.

Comment: @MiguelCartagena Sorry. Edited it into the OP.

Comment: @kentcdodds I agree. But, since the main point of this is for me to learn node, I was thinking I shouldn't jump into higher level modules. The same reason why I am trying not to use express to run the server. Do you agree with me, since you have used both?

Comment: @Rohit I guess you just have to draw a line. I definitely *could* be a better programmer if I knew how to write everything in assembly code, but I actually want to build things of value and re-inventing the wheel in that way is a bit of a waste of time. So, as an exercise I think you're good to try and figure it out without MongooseJS. You'll get it working I'm sure. But learning MongooseJS is really useful as well. I don't know if I'm better at using MongooseJS because I know how to use MongoDB without it...

Comment: @MiguelCartagena You can find the full code at [github](https://github.com/rsivapr/beginNode/tree/pastebin).

Comment: @kentcdodds I agree. I'll look into that next. Thanks for the advice. MongooseJS does seem pretty good.

Comment: and how many document you have in this collection?

Comment: @Rohit, have you had any success connecting to the MongoDB session? You are running MongoDB right? In the MongoDB console is it showing that it has an open connection?

Comment: It start's out with just two, as you can see in the `memory.js` file in the github repo.

Comment: @kentcdodds That seems like something I have not done.  MongoDB console does not seem to be updating the documents that I insert. Is that the problem then?

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to claim that this is best practice at all. In fact I think that my `addAdminUser` function is total rubish. But when I wrote this I had no idea what I was doing. Moving to Mongoose was a great decision. But this is my DatabaseController for spendmycents.com. Glean what you can about how to open a connection to mongo.

```
'use strict';

var DatabaseController = (function() {
  var mongo = require('mongodb');
  var logger = require('winston');
  var openConnectionToCollection;
  var getOrCreateClient;
  var deleteObjectByQuery;

  getOrCreateClient = function(callback) {
    var server = new mongo.Server(process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST, process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT, {auto_reconnect: false});
    var username = process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_USERNAME;
    var password = process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PASSWORD;
    var finishClientSetup, addAdminUser, authenticateToClient;

    var client = new mongo.Db(process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_NAME, server, {w: 1, strict: true});

    logger.info('Client created');

    client.open(function(error, openedClient) {
      logger.info('Client opened');
      if (error) {
        throw error;
      }
      finishClientSetup(openedClient);
    });

    finishClientSetup = function(openedClient) {
      var usersCollection = new mongo.Collection(openedClient, 'system.users');
      logger.info('Looking for users in system.users');
      usersCollection.findOne({user: username}, function(error, doc) {
        if (error) {
          logger.warn('Error finding user in system.users!');
          logger.error(error);
          throw error;
        }
        if (!doc) {
          addAdminUser(openedClient);
        } else {
          authenticateToClient(openedClient);
        }
      });
    };

    addAdminUser = function(openedClient) {
      logger.info('No user found. Adding user.');
      openedClient.addUser(username, password, function(error, result) {
        if (!result || error) {
          logger.warn('Error adding admin user to client!');
          logger.error(error);
          throw 'Error adding admin user to client! ' + error;
        }
        authenticateToClient(openedClient);
      });
    };

    authenticateToClient = function(openedClient) {
      logger.info('Authenticating to client');
      openedClient.authenticate(username, password, function(error, result) {
        logger.info('Closing client');
        openedClient.close();
        if (result && !error) {
          logger.info('Success authenticating');
          callback(error, openedClient);
        } else {
          logger.warn('Failure in authenticating!');
          logger.error(error);
          throw 'Authentication to database failed! ' + error;
        }
      });
    };
  };

  openConnectionToCollection = function(collectionName, callback) {
    if (!collectionName) {
      throw 'collectionName must be defined!';
    }
    getOrCreateClient(function(error, receivedClient) {
      if (error) {
        throw error;
      }
      receivedClient.open(function(error, openedClient) {
        if (error) {
          callback(error, null);
        } else {
          callback(new mongo.Collection(openedClient, collectionName));
        }
      });
    });
  };

  deleteObjectByQuery = function(collectionName, query, callback) {
    openConnectionToCollection(collectionName, function(collection) {
      collection.remove(query, {save: true}, function(error, numberRemoved) {
        collection.db.close();
        callback(error, numberRemoved);
      });
    });
  };

  return {
    findAll: function(collectionName, callback) {
      openConnectionToCollection(collectionName, function(collection) {
        collection.find().toArray(function(error, docs) {
          collection.db.close();
          callback(error, docs);
        });
      });
    },
    saveObject: function(collectionName, object, callback) {
      openConnectionToCollection(collectionName, function(collection) {
        collection.save(object, {safe: true}, function(error, doc) {
          collection.db.close();
          callback(error, doc);
        });
      });
    },
    findOneObjectById: function(collectionName, idString, callback) {
      this.findOneObjectByQuery(collectionName, {_id: new mongo.ObjectID(idString)}, callback);
    },
    findOneObjectByQuery: function(collectionName, query, callback) {
      openConnectionToCollection(collectionName, function(collection) {
        collection.findOne(query, function(error, doc) {
          collection.db.close();
          callback(error, doc);
        });
      });
    },
    deleteObjectById: function(collectionName, idString, callback) {
      deleteObjectByQuery(collectionName, {_id: new mongo.ObjectID(idString)}, callback);
    }
  };
})();

module.exports = DatabaseController;
```